# Kotlin ImageView Problem With GetView Function Type Mismatch

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have having problems on the fourth line. In my code, `getLogo` returns an integer (ID) of an image. I now want to use the drawable ID for the image and put in in a ImageView with the specified id. However, on the left hand of the equal sign, I am getting the error of `variable expected` and on the right side it says `Type Mismatch ... Required: ImageView Found: Int`.

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.layoutlistviewloan, parent, false)
    row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.institutionImage) = loansModel.loan[position].institution.getLogo()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById()` is a function that returns a `View` (in this case you're saying it's an `ImageView`). It's not a variable (`val` or `var`) that you can assign a value to.

I'm guessing you want to find that `ImageView` in the layout, and then set it to display your drawable ID. So you need to chain a [`setImageResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int)) call to the ImageView after you grab it

```
row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.institutionImage).setImageResource(drawableId)
```

you *could* stick the "getting the drawable ID" code in there as the `setImageResource` parameter

```
row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.institutionImage).setImageResource(loansModel.loan[position].institution.getLogo())
```

but personally I'd just set that as a variable to make it more readable instead of doing too much in one line (it can get confusing!)

```
val logoId = loansModel.loan[position].institution.getLogo()
row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.institutionImage).setImageResource(logoId)
```